# How can I get value from application.properties using SpelExpressionParser?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I tried to pass "${<some.property>}" as key parameter, but got: "After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'".

Here's the function:

```
fun parse(key: String): String {
        val context = StandardEvaluationContex()
        context.addPropertyAccessor(EnvironmentAccessor())

        return SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(key).getValue(context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @Value annotation and access the property in whichever Spring bean you're using

```
@Value("${propertyName}")
private String propertyName;
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I need to get value via SpelExpressionParser